# How to open an selected object with powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to figure out how to open the selected object I just selected below.

I understand it might have some issues due to it might not know the file it's opening but even an "open with" option would work.

Basically I want to open the last file I was working with similar to the outlook attach file feature where it shows the last document you were working with.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\replace user name here\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent' | 
    Where-Object { -not $_.PsIsContainer } |
    Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
    Select-Object -first 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe to `Invoke-Item` :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\replace user name here\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent' | Where-Object { -not $_.PsIsContainer } | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -first 1 | invoke-item
```

or, wrap it in a scriptblock:

```
invoke-item {Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\replace user name here\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent' | Where-Object { -not $_.PsIsContainer } | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -first 1}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :) First one it does open the folder where it is located in documents in this case :) .  I've found if I use R arrow L Arrow  down and up it will highlight / and press enter it will open it.  Definitely getting closer :)  I could probably do sendkeys for the rest, but hoping for a better way.

Comment: ah - probably need to add ```-ExpandProperty  FullName``` to the ```Select-Object``` cmdlet so that the full name of the object selected is piped to ```Invoke-Item``` instead of the parent directory item

Answer (score 1):

The `Invoke-Item` cmdlet works like double-clicking an item in explorer.  That should run the default association for the file.

Comment: Thank you so much! :)  I haven't been exposed to much Powershell, but I really like it so far trying to simplify my some of my redundant steps. "open do this save close" without admin access or able to install software or libraries.